SSDR as hour builder prior to CPL in the UK?
In the UK, to start CPL training, you need to meet the following requirements:

Hold a Private Pilot Licence (PPL)
Pass all ATPL Theoretical Knowledge examinations
Hold a Night Rating
Hold a Class 1 Aviation Medical
Have completed 150 hours of flight time as a pilot, including:

100 hours as Pilot In Command (PIC)
A Cross Country flight of at least 300nm with full stop landings at two different aerodromes.




My questions are:

What aircraft class must the 100 PIC hours be completed in?
If I already have a PPL(A) with a night rating, can I complete the remaining required hours in a Single Seat De-Regulated (SSDR) microlight (an example being the SD-1)?


After re-reading the CPL page on the CAA website...

Flight experience amassed in aeroplanes classified as Microlight (Aeroplanes), cannot be counted towards meeting any of the above requirements.

source: CAA CPL (See the "Experience requirements that must be met before the skill test" section).
